# How To Use React or Angular To Create Reuseable Galleries That Only Load When Needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, reactjs

I'm a self-learner and this is just one of the things I cannot wrap my head around. I use nodejs for all my web applications and wondering if react can solve the problem I am facing.

The problem: what todo when you need to show a pop-up image gallery that showcases multiple images. But we don't need to look this gallery every time the page loads, only when using clicks the open galley button.

A similar example would be what Airbnb have achieved on their listing pages:
https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/432044

Now the page doesn't load all the gallery pictures when page first renders.

But when you click on the view photos, it opens the gallery, but then loads the pictures and I've noticed it has a div containing data-reactroot.

Are they using some sort of react magic? Or is it angular?

I'd really love to be able to build my components for easy reuse, but more importantly, I'd just like to understand what's going on so that the gallery content is only loaded when the photos are opened.

If someone can summarise in a paragraph, what is going on, I'm sure I can go away and learn to replicate it. I'm just not sure what I'm trying to replicate at the moment.

Comment: Have you had a look at angular modules? Lazily loading the modules could definitely solve this: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use React for that, you just need a conditional render. Basically you have a toggle in the component's state (a simple bool). And in your render for the parent component you can have something like:

```
render() {
    <div>
        ...
        { this.state.showPhotos ? <PhotoPopup /> : null }
        ...
    </div>
}
```

If the toggle is false, that component won't get rendered so it doesn't load. When they click the button and change the state, the toggle is true so that component WILL get rendered and the photo popup will be displayed (loading photos in the process).

That's one way to do it in React anyway. Don't forget to handle loading of photos (i.e. have some visual indication that photos are loading)

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach is that you write a small React or Angular app. The responsibility of this app is probably just to render a "show photos" button, and then when it's clicked dynamically add the photo gallery HTML to the page, which is turn triggers the browser to download the images. The app and all its logic is bundled up in a single JavaScript file.

Have a read of the React docs,

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html

Then start with create-react-app. It's Facebook's recommended way to build simple to medium complexity apps - it's all you'll need to achieve the above.

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

Comment: The distinction between having the show button and further logic being part of the same mini "app", working towards a single common goal has greatly helped me comprehend this. Great points and resources. Going to make my first component/app soon. 

You mention that " It's Facebook's recommended way to build simple to medium complexity apps", what do they recommend for the complex apps? Or why don't they recommend this approach for complex apps?

Comment: IMO create-react-app is a good starting point for nearly all React projects, since it helps so much with setting up the tooling and compile steps. At a certain level of complexity you can "eject" create-react-app and start digging around in the project config however you want ("eject" is creat-react-app terminology - have a read in the docs). For truly large/complex apps I guess the advice would be to roll your own bespoke build steps and project structure, but always best to start off simple and only increase complexity when you feel some pain.